# IIS Application Pool Crashing for any .net application - NullReferenceException in PipelineModuleStepContainer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-10, debug-diagnostic-tool

**Hello,**
I'm running into an IIS problem for days and nights, it seems the application pools are crushing for any dot net application not just for a specific code, I searched a lot and I tried tons of solutions:

1. Remove and reinstall IIS
2. Update windows 10
3. Update nuggets libraries to latest
4. Update .net framework to latest

And nothing from the above solved the problem.

I downloaded the Diagnostic Dialog tools and I created a dump file: [here](https://app.box.com/s/1hxy9iz6x1xlzyit032wvephe97okrnv)

Please help, I know there are many posts concerning similar issue but I tried them all and nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if you just re-install the IIS, it will still use the previous IIS applicationhost config file.

I suggest you could try to follow below article to perform a clean reinstallation of IIS.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/01/16/how-to-perform-a-clean-reinstallation-of-iis/